# Traceback error during plaidml installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu

because I have no Nvidia GPU to use CUDA, I'm trying to install plaidml. I'm using the operating system Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Before I tried to install plaidml, I checked the output of the clinfo command, which is:

```
Number of platforms                             1
Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Platform Vendor                                 Intel
Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.1.1
Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd
Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel

Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 1
Device Name                                     Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2
Device Vendor                                   Intel
Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.1.1
Driver Version                                  1.1.1
Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 beignet 1.1.1
Device Type                                     GPU
Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
Max compute units                               16
Max clock frequency                             1000MHz
Device Partition                                (core)
Max number of sub-devices                       1
Supported partition types                       None, None, None
Max work item dimensions                        3
Max work item sizes                             512x512x512
Max work group size                             512
Preferred work group size multiple              16
Preferred / native vector sizes                 
char                                            16 / 8       
short                                           8 / 8       
int                                             4 / 4       
long                                            2 / 2       
half                                            0 / 8        (n/a)
float                                           4 / 4       
double                                          0 / 2        (n/a)
Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
Denormals                                       No
Infinity and NANs                               Yes
Round to nearest                                Yes
Round to zero                                   No
Round to infinity                               No
IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add                 No
Support is emulated in software                 No
Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations    No
Double-precision Floating-point support         (n/a)
Address bits                                    32, Little-Endian
Global memory size                              2147483648 (2GiB)
Error Correction support                        No
Max memory allocation                           1073741824 (1024MiB)
Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
Global Memory cache size                        8192
Global Memory cache line                        64 bytes
Image support                                   Yes
Max number of samplers per kernel               16
Max size for 1D images from buffer              65536 pixels
Max 1D or 2D image array size                   2048 images
Max 2D image size                               8192x8192 pixels
Max 3D image size                               8192x8192x2048 pixels
Max number of read image args                   128
Max number of write image args                  8
Local memory type                               Global
Local memory size                               65536 (64KiB)
Max constant buffer size                        134217728 (128MiB)
Max number of constant args                     8
Max size of kernel argument                     1024
Queue properties                                
Out-of-order execution                          No
Profiling                                       Yes
Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
Profiling timer resolution                      80ns
Execution capabilities                          
Run OpenCL kernels                              Yes
Run native kernels                              Yes
SPIR versions                                   <printDeviceInfo:138: get   SPIR versions size : error -30>
printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
Built-in kernels                                __cl_copy_region_align4;__cl_copy_region_align16;__cl_cpy_region_unalign_same_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_dst_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_src_offset;__cl_copy_buffer_rect;__cl_copy_image_1d_to_1d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_2d;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_3d;__cl_fill_region_unalign;__cl_fill_region_align2;__cl_fill_region_align4;__cl_fill_region_align8_2;__cl_fill_region_align8_4;__cl_fill_region_align8_8;__cl_fill_region_align8_16;__cl_fill_region_align128;__cl_fill_image_1d;__cl_fill_image_1d_array;__cl_fill_image_2d;__cl_fill_image_2d_array;__cl_fill_image_3d;
Device Available                                Yes
Compiler Available                              Yes
Linker Available                                Yes
Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd

NULL platform behavior 
clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Intel Gen OCL Driver
clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [Intel]
clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [Intel]
clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  Success (1)
Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
Device Name                                   Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2
clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
Device Name                                   Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2

ICD loader properties
ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
ICD loader Version                              2.2.8
ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 1.2
NOTE:   your OpenCL library declares to support OpenCL 1.2,
    but it seems to support up to OpenCL 2.1 too.
```

I want to use the device 'Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile' in order to compute deep learning projects on my GPU.

I tried to install plaidml according to this guide: https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml

I created and activated a virtual environment via:

```
virtualenv plaidml
source plaidml/bin/activate
```

within this virtual environment I installed plaidml and plaidbench via:

```
pip install plaidml-keras plaidbench
```

But if I run the command (also within this virtual environment)

```
plaidml-setup
```

to select the correct device, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 155, in load_library
return ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plaidml/libplaidml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/e1326196/plaidml/bin/plaidml-setup", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plaidml/plaidml_setup.py", line 15, in main
ctx = plaidml.Context()
File "/home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 858, in Context
return plaidml.context.Context(_lib())
File "/home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 758, in _lib
_impl_lib = _Library()
File "/home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
lib = load_library('libplaidml.so', ['lib'])
File "/home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plaidml/__init__.py", line 165, in load_library
return ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/libplaidml.so)
```

I don't know why it doesn't work and what this error mean. Can someone help me to fix this error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I work without venv on Debian 10.
I was searching for the misterious libplaidml.so and finally found it !
It's in `~/.local/lib/libplaidml.so`
Now we want plaidml to be able to find it's own library and local configuration files which lie in `~/.local/share/plaidml/config.json`.
It also can't find them. So it's kind of buggy or not synchronized with the way python3 handles local/per user installations.
Looking into source code of `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidml/settings.py` we see this code:

```
 def _find_config(name):
        prefixes = [
            sys.prefix,
            os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'local'),
        ]
    ...
```

It gets sys.prefix which contains '/usr' instead of  '~/.local' so it tries to load `/usr/share/plaidml/experimental.json` instead of '~/.local/share/plaidml/experimental.json`

Answer (score 0):

> OSError:
>   /home/e1326196/plaidml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plaidml/libplaidml.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I actually just ran into the same problem.
From my limited understanding, this means when building something, the linker cannot find the shared library it believes is located above.

In my case, I tried to uninstall the plaidml through pip3, then I saw the location of the library file actually was /usr/lib for some reason. So I move the library file (I should've copied) to the above address in the error, and it worked. (in a sense that it shows me another error, but that maybe specific to me).